# Apple pay sheet not showing up for Apple app reviewer

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, applepay, passkit

My app keeps getting rejected by the App Review team due to the fact that the Apple Pay button in my app is unresponsive on their device when they tap it. The Apple Pay sheet shows up perfectly fine on my device but never completes the payment (error says my debit card number is invalid, my card works perfectly fine everywhere else, not sure how to fix this, but not the main issue here).

I am not worried about paying with Apple Pay on my app simply because I will not be the one using my app but I do want to ensure it works for everybody else since Apple is bringing it up as a reoccurring issue.

Here is my function for presenting the Apple Pay sheet:

```
{
    guard let cost = actualCostOfEvent.text else { return }
    guard let name = nameOfEvent else { return }
    let text = cost
    let textWithout$ = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "$", with: "")
    guard let finalCost = Double(textWithout$) else { return }
    let fee = finalCost / Double(12.0)
    let roundedFee = floor(fee * 100) / 100.0
    let total = finalCost + roundedFee
    
    let paymentRequest = StripeAPI.paymentRequest(withMerchantIdentifier: "merchant.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx",
                                                  country: "CA",
                                                  currency: "CAD")
    
    paymentRequest.supportedNetworks = [.visa, .masterCard, .interac, .amex, .discover]
    
    
    paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems = [
        PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: name , amount: NSDecimalNumber(value: finalCost)),
        PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Service Fee", amount: NSDecimalNumber(value: roundedFee)),
        PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "XXXXXX", amount: NSDecimalNumber(value: total))
    ]
 
    guard let applePayController = STPApplePayContext(paymentRequest: paymentRequest, delegate: self) else { return }
    
    if StripeAPI.canSubmitPaymentRequest(paymentRequest) {
        applePayController.presentApplePay {
            self.startApplePayCheckout()
        }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why the Apple Pay sheet doesn't show up for the App reviewer, any suggestions or things needed to be changed? If not, I will just have to submit an appeal.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your code, and it works perfectly fine; the ApplePay sheet is displayed for me. You may want to confirm with Apple what iOS version they are testing and submit an appeal.

A few notes just in case:

- You don’t need to check if StripeAPI.canSubmitPaymentRequest(paymentRequest). When you initialized STPApplePayContext it automatically did the check for you: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/master/Stripe/STPApplePayContext.swift#L87
- If you are using a test key, you can complete the payment as long as your real card information is correct. You won’t be charged while using a test key.

Comment: Great, thanks for the reassurance. @orakaro